# Way to tell if user clicked cancel in Facebook auth with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase I have users authenticate with Facebook if they aren't already authenticated:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log('Yes a user!', user)
  } else {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
  }
}
```

Works great, unless someone clicks "Cancel" on the Facebook authorization page. The user gets redirected back to my page. Since the user still isn't logged in, I redirect them back to Facebook...

Is there a way to tell if a user clicked "Cancel" on Facebook so I can give them an appropriate message back?